# Client/Server communication using TCP/IP under TLS 1.3

Tags: c, ssl, tcp, gnutls

I want to write a client and server in C preferably, simple C++ if necessary.

The server will run on some flavor of Linux, the client is for testing the server.

I want to ensure messages are received and error free; therefore I will use TCP.

I want them to communicate securely; thus I will use the latest version of TLS (v1.3).

I intend to use the GnuTLS library for reasons:

- Actively updated by reputable open source project
- License permits selling product

Given the above, if implemented and tested, I could claim that the client/server communication is secure, reliable (a.k.a. assured), and error-checked. Yes?

Am I missing something? Is anything patently false?

Edit: certificates... i think i'm missing something about certificates to protect against man in the middle attacks...

Answer (score -1):

TLS is a complex topic. Depending on your specific code the TLS connection might succeed even if you fail to properly validate the certificate. Thus, just based on what you state so far in your question it cannot be assured that the data are transferred with proper end-to-end protection and that no man in the middle can manipulate the data.